# How to use loop statements and condition statements in TOSCA?

Tags: tosca

I am new to TOSCA, kindly guide me How to use loop statements and condition statements in TOSCA...

Thanks in advance.
Sreeni

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way to find help on this is to refer Tosca documentation.

Please check this : https://support.tricentis.com/community/manuals_detail.do?lang=en&version=10.0.0&url=tchb/conditional_statements.htm

**The above link refers to the manual for Tosca 10.0**

Answer (score 0):

You can use IF statement for condition, in which you can compare values within tbox set buffer and choose the direction with Then or Else statement.

For looping there are two options While and Do-While loops. Syntax remains same like other programming languages, only thing need to take care is that you need to mention repetition count for looping. By default repetition count for loop is 30, which can be changed to any count you want, just it gives false error when the count has reached to maximum if the loop doesn't end at 'n-1' count.
To avoid this false error you can first take count of elements on which actually you want to apply the loop and then set that value to repetition count by passing a buffer value.